# Bootstrap: Content spanning multiple grid columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap grid is divided into three columns: a sidebar and two content columns.

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    Sidebar column.
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    Left content column.
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7">
    Right content column.
</div>
```

I'd like to display a confirmation message that spans across the two content columns but not the sidebar.  Is it possible to do this without altering the bootstrap grid layout?

Example (in ugly HTML tables):
http://jsfiddle.net/jcCUs/

Since the confirmation messages will only be displayed occasionally it doesn't seem ideal to dynamically change the Bootstrap grid layout based on the presence or absence of a message.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately, a solution that requires altering the width and/or proportions of the columns (as suggested below) is not viable.  Too many other elements on the page (and website) are based on the existing 2-3-7 layout and we can't scrap the overall proportions just to integrate confirmation messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around with the Bootstrap grid, my current working solution is below.

It's more straight forward than one might expect... you just stack the columns!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    Sidebar (2)
    <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    Confirmation Message (10)
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    Left Content (3)
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    Right Content (7)
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ravQm/

Some notes:

- This works only if the sidebar is taller than the confirmation message, which should usually be the case.
- Bootstrap 3 provides a number of **offset**, **push**, and **pull** classes that might be very helpful in this situation.  However: `Those resets are available for medium and large grid tiers only, since they start only at the (second) small grid tier.` Since we're using "xs" columns in this particular case, they can't be utilized here. But see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

I'm still a little uneasy about this because I'm not sure I have a firm grasp on exactly how the Bootstrap 3 grid functions.  But I've tested it a few different ways and will update if I discover more as we apply it in practice.

Comment: Update: This actually works quite well so issue solved! It maintains the existing layout and stacks the confirmation message on top of both content columns as desired, without any discernible side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the "left" and "right" columns in a 10 sized column, then display them as rows, with the warning message row about it. Like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    Sidebar column.
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="row" id="confirmation_msg">
        <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-success">
            <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
            <strong>Update:</strong> Widths and structure redesigned.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"  style="background-color: #d9edf7;">
            Left content column.   
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color: #fcf8e3;">
            Right content column.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the confirmation message row is ID'd as "confirmation_msg" so you can hide/show it as needed.

UPDATE: [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MC8sF/)

Comment: You're welcome @tino.  I didn't put it in the example (because you didn't ask) but a BootStrap "alert" might look good in there. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts

Comment: Whoops, @PhilNicholas, I spoke too soon! I tried this in practice, and if I understand correctly, it seems that Bootstrap expects the sum of all columns *within each nested row* to add up to 12. 

In other words, simply making sure that the sum of the inner columns (7+3) adds up to the value of the wrapper column (10) does not appear to work since Bootstrap expects the inner columns to sum to 12.

This messes up the column proportions. Hopefully this way-too-convoluted demo can better explain what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/st72T/1/

Comment: Tino, here's an updated JSFiddle with the native BS3 alert: http://jsfiddle.net/wXV3Q/     The row will disappear when the user clicks the "X" to close the success message, bringing the content columns back up to their normal position.  Also, to be clear, the solution I posted didn't float or overlay because that did not meet the design requirement as demonstrated in your HTML table-based example in the question you posted.

Comment: Good catch on the totals in the subordinate row.  I've updated the posted answer to correct as such.  I'd still highly recommend the native BS3 alert (with or without fade-out animation, it's up to you).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't quite do it since, even though it sums correctly now, the column proportions have been altered. In relation to the wrapper column, left is now 4/12 instead of 3/10.  And right is 8/12 instead of 7/10.

Comment: I know the fractions will change. I don't we have a choice since Bootstrap is a percent-based grid system that is based on fractions of 12.  Insofar as is possible under Bootstrap, I believe the grid layout I've posted above satisfies your positioning requirements in the original question; even more so since the alert will self-hide and your columns will be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks again, Phil. Changing the entire layout of the website to integrate alerts just isn't an option for us. If no alternative solution presents itself, I'll gladly award you the answer for your help!

Comment: You're quite welcome, Tino. You might not have to change anything at all, if you instead create the message row (ID above is "confirmation_msg") dynamically using jQuery and then insert it in the DOM.  It's bit trickier, but I've retrofitted sites in that way in the past.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to wrapping the 3 and 7 in a 10 sized column as PhilNicholas suggested, you could change the `alert` position to absolute so that it overlays the left and right columns. Otherwise the content will slide up/down when the alert displays.

```
.alert {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/91235

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly pointed out, offsets can be used to have a display as you desire.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="well">col-xs-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-2"><div class="alert alert-success">Updated Successfully!</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="well">col-xs-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="well">col-xs-7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [**here**](http://bootply.com/111509)

Comment: you have a typo in the class attribute with value ".col-sm-offset-2", remove the leading dot